# How to access data from a span tag

Tags: html, webflow

I am using a thrid party service and they give me one line of code:

They said that when I put it on webflow then, the data will pop up. I put it in webflow, and it works
When I run the website and use the inspect element function to have a look at the data. That one line of code they give me now becomes something like this in the browser:

```
<span data-o-member="CustomProperty">
    <!--a bunch of data they promised to give me -->
</span>
```

Why does the data just suddenly appear when I put it on webflow. And is there a way I can access it? I am asking this because I am trying to do some custom code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data-attributes values in JavaScript.
Add an id or a class to your `<span/>` or to its parent if you can't modify it :

```html
<span id="my-data-to-pick" data-o-member="CustomProperty">
    <!--a bunch of data they promised to give me -->
</span>
```

```js
const mySpan = document.getElementById('my-data-to-pick');
const oMember = mySpan.getAttribute('data-o-member');

console.log(oMember);
```